# Browsing nautilus folder containing a dvi file -- apparmor/evince error

Tags: evince, apparmor, dvi

If a browse a nautilus folder that contains a .dvi file, I get errors that pop onto my screen:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think that this is due to the thumbnailer processing the file. I don't care about getting thumbnails for dvi files.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: I've added a bounty to try and get an answer for this! Any help?

Comment: have you checked file permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable thumbnails for `dvi` files. Open a terminal and type the following commands:

1. Clean the thumbnails cache folder:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails
   ```
2. blacklist the `dvi` files:

   ```
   dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/thumbnailers/disable "['application/x-dvi']"
   ```
3. Finally restart Nautilus:

   ```
   nautilus -q
   ```